# Java regex for a simple pattern

Tags: java, regex

I would like a write a regex in Java to filter strings like this: `FROM: User.0@asdd.tst.com`.

What I exactly want to filter looks like this:

```
["FROM" on beginning of the line] 
[undefinied number of white space character] 
[":" colon] 
[undefinied number of white space character] 
[any alphanumeric character plus any point(".") character) "] 
["@" at] 
[any alphanumeric character plus any point(".") character) "] 
["end of line character"]
```

I've already tried this: `^FROM\\s*:\\s*\\.*@\\.*`, but it doesn't work. (I used double slashes because I wanna pass it to a Pattern like string.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten alphanumeric characters:

```
^FROM\s*:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+
```